# DataGridView does not refresh on Collection Modified

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, datagridview

In my app i have a DataGridView bound to BindingList, object inherits INotifyPropertyChanged to inform change, same thread.

Problem is that DataGridView does not refresh the UI, on selecting the row the values in the row are updated, so i tried to use DataGridView.Refresh() at the end, which worked now the values are all updated on the DataGridView UI.

But the actual process is long running, it downloads from web, so i need to show the values as they are updated.

Please Suggest.

```
public class Proxy : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string IPAddress
        {
            get
            {
                return ipaddress;
            }
            set
            {
                ipaddress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IPAddress");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
}

SortableSearchableList<Proxy> proxyList = new SortableSearchableList<Proxy>();
proxydatagrid.DataSource = proxyList;
```

I WANT TO UPDATE DATAGRIDVIEW AS COLLECTION IS MODIFIED, NOT LATER.

Comment: Could you please show some code - particularly of how you have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and how you are adding the items to your binding list and setting the DataSource property.

Comment: This works perfectly for me, the only difference in my code is that I use an ordinary BindingList<T> could you try your code with just the standard BindingList<T> to check that there isn't a problem in your implementation of SortableSearchableList<T>

Comment: One more thought - when you say you have a long running process, is this in a background worker? You will need to be careful that your running on the right thread, using something like the ReportProgress method.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a row by row update.

You need to start a thread, tell your app which row to update. If well done, each row should update one by one.

An other option is to store your results in an other datatable or dataset and when the operation is done, you replace your datagrid's datatable with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to call `DataGrid.Items.Refresh()` to refresh the items rather than `DataGridView.Refresh()`